# Is there a function that maps all integers from $1$ to $m\cdot n$ in ascending order to an $m\times n$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, functions

Is there a function that maps all integers from $1$ to $m\cdot n\:$ in ascending order to an $m\times n\:$ matrix so that: $(a_{11}=1,\:a_{12}=2,\:...,\:a_{m(n-1)}=m\cdot n-1,\:a_{mn}=m\cdot n)$ that can be expressed though only $i$ and $j$ where $i$ and $j$ are the indexes of elements $a_{ij}$ in a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is $a_{ij}=(i-1)\cdot n+j$ what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes thank you , very cool :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go \begin{align}&A_{\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}{n}\right\rfloor+1,\ x-n\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}n\right\rfloor}=x\\ &A_{ij}=n(i-1)+j\end{align}